# is it possible to reverse a dictionary in python using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want to reverse dictionary `key, value` pairs using a dictionary comprehension, but if the new dictionary has more than one value for a key then it is getting replaced with the last value.

Is it possible to append to the values in the new dictionary if a key is repeated, using a comprehension?

Input:

```
test_di = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'2'}
```

Code:

```
{v:k for k,v in test_di.items()}
```

Output of this code:

```
{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'd'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'1': ['a'], '3': ['c'], '2': ['b','d']}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'reverse'?  In Python, dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I think he wants to swap keys for values, and values for keys. It would then use the key to find the most recently assigned value for that key?

Comment: Can you edit your question to at least include a sample input dictionary and the desired output, and ideally a dictionary comprehension you tried?

Comment: Sort `dict.items()` based on values and then group them on values using `itertools.groupby`, but that's O(N Log N) and not worth the effort.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to do it in a reasonable way (i.e. `O(N)` time) with a dictionary comprehension. The comprehension simply can't handle duplicated values.

However, it's quite easy with a regular loop:

```
d = {}
for key, value in old_d.items():
    d.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks. For some reason I don't think I have ever used `setdefault`

Answer (score 2):

A `defaultdict` would be the most efficient approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict

test_di = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'2'}

d = defaultdict(list)
for v,k in test_di.items():
    d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but it sounds like you want to store multiple values at a single key in a dictionary.

This is not possible, you may want to look at storing a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OrderedDict` and reverse the keys. A normal `dict` does not keep track of the order of the keys.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict1 = OrderedDict([('Name', 'Jon'), ('Race', 'Latino'), ('Job', 'Nurse')])
reversed_dict1 = OrderedDict([(key, dict1.get(key)) for key in reversed(dict1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible (but it’s not the most efficient solution):

```
d = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'2'}

{v1: [k1 for k1, v2 in d.items() if v1 == v2] for v1 in d.values()}
# {'1': ['a'], '2': ['b', 'd'], '3': ['c']}
```