# Dictionary Comprehension in Python for key:[1,2,3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

While I've been improving my Python skills I have one question.
My code is below:

```
# def invertDictionary(dict):
#     new_dict = {} 
#     for key, value in dict.items():
#                 if value in new_dict:
#                         new_dict[value].append(key) 
#                 else: 
#                     new_dict[value]=[key]
#     return new_dict

def invertDictionary(dict):
    new_dict = {value:([key] if value else [key]) for key, value in dict.items()}
    return new_dict;

invertDictionary({'a':3, 'b':3, 'c':3})
```

I am trying to get output like `{3:['a','b','c']}`. I have achieved that using a normal for-loop; I just want to know how to get these results using a Dictionary Comprehension. I tried but in append it's getting an error. Please let me know  how to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a dict comprehension but you can get rid of `if ... else ...` statement in your function by using `collections.defaultdict` or doing something like `new_dict.setdefault(value, []).append(key)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32509257/12671057

Comment: there is no elegant way of doing it with comprehension without some sort of prepossessing

Comment: It's possible, but it forces you to use a potentially inefficient approach, getting a quadratic time algorithm where a naive for-loop approach would give you linear time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well it's also possible in linear time, so I wouldn't say "force".

Comment: @KellyBundy no, it isn't. Go ahead an demonstrate a solution that had worst-case linear time. In this case, where `values` are unique, so `set(d.values())` has the same number of values as `d.values()`, or at least, as long as it is sufficiently unique (all of this barring that the hash map itself is not failing to act ideally)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga https://stackoverflow.com/a/65080121/12671057 (oh well, not quite the same task, but imagine `items` instead of `enumerate`)

Comment: @KellyBundy that is a gross abuse of comprehension constructs that should always be avoided, for decency's sake...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I only said possible, not reasonable :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I mean, I could define a function, `def foo(): ...` that does whatever side-effect I want to accoplish anything. That doesn't mean we should consider `{foo() for _ in range(1)}` a valid approach worth considering

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd say [copperfield's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111545/12671057) is decent (at least not a hack) and also sub-quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

You missed that you *also* need a list comprehension to build the list.
Iterate over the values in the dict, and build the needed list of keys for each one.

Note that this is a quadratic process, whereas the canonical (and more readable) `for` loop is linear.

```
d = {'a':3, 'b':3, 'c':3, 'e':4, 'f':4, 'g':0}
inv_dict = {v: [key for key, val in d.items() if val == v]
               for v in set(d.values())}
```

result:

```
{0: ['g'],
 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 4: ['e', 'f']
}
```

Will this do?

Comment: Great answer! I was about to post something like this but I didn't think to have a list comprehension inside the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, this is quadratic time, making it a much worse option than a straightforward `for` loop.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Regardless of its efficiency, it definitely answers the question.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Stack Overflow is not a place to just blindly hand out code. If you are posting an answer that has a clear disadvantage, the answer should be improved to *note* that disadvantage. Sometimes, when someone asks "how do I shoot myself in the foot", we need to answer with "well, you really shouldn't shoot yourself in the foot (but if you *really* want to, you can pull the trigger here...)"

Comment: I agree that the execution time is worse.  The question is not how to do it most efficiently; it's how to do it with a dict comprehension.  The `for` loop is also more readable.

Comment: @M-Chen-3: If a question asks "how do I shoot myself in the foot" without indicating an understanding of the consequences, "load gun, aim towards foot, pull trigger" can't be considered a good answer without at least some sort of warning.

Comment: I *did* call out that this is non-linear.

Comment: @Prune yeah, perhaps a slight modification to the phrasing, use "a non linear-time algorithm" to make it clear. I feel like "non-linear process" is kind of ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

while your original version with a regular for loop is the best solution for this, here is a variation on @Prune answer that doesn't goes over the dict multiple times

```
>>> import itertools
>>> d = {'a':3, 'b':3, 'c':3, 'e':4, 'f':4, 'g':0}
>>> {group_key:[k for k,_ in dict_items] 
     for group_key,dict_items in itertools.groupby(
                                             sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[-1]),
                                             key=lambda x:x[-1]
                                             )
      }
{0: ['g'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['e', 'f']}
>>>
```

first we sorted the items of the dict by value with a key function to [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) using a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) to extract the value part of the item tuple, then we use the [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group those with the same value together with the same key function and finally with a list comprehension extract just the key

--

as noted by Kelly, we can use the [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method from the dict to get the value to make it shorter and use the fact that iteration over a dict give you its keys

```
>>> {k: list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=d.get), d.get)}
{0: ['g'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['e', 'f']}
>>>
```

Comment: Good idea. Shorter version: `{k: list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=d.get), d.get)}`

Comment: @Copperfield Thank you its really nice solution .. :)

Answer (score -3):

You could use a `defalutdict` and the `append` method.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
{dict2[v].append(k) for k, v in dict1.items()}

dict2
>>> defaultdict(list, {3: ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

Comment: That's no dictionary comprehension, not even an abuse of one.

Comment: Don't use comprehension constructs for side-effects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the constructive feedback.

Comment: @TimothyHelton yeah, unfortunately this is like a cardinal sin on the python tag, so it's a downvote magnet. I wouldn't feel too bad about it, a lot of people do stuf like this